# how to handle text div in different screen resolutions according to parent div

Tags: html, css

Hi i am designing a website..
Here is the url 
https://ifixandrepair.com/ifar/ifixandrepairwellington/

I have designed it on 1366*768, 15 inch screen as u can see here on screenfly 
http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=https%3A//ifixandrepair.com/ifar/ifixandrepairwellington/&w=1366&h=768&a=1&s=1

Its giving me perfect result the way i want. But on changing screen size for desktops 13-24 inch i am unable to handle the text div class .span6 as my banner image changes its size without cropping and squeezing i want this class content (text buttons text box) to exactly change size and position(the same place where they are placed in 15 inch screen) accordingly. 
I don't want to put all media queries for each respective screen. I know position absolute is the real reason but on removing it i cant manage the design. Any suggestions i can manage it properly.

CSS:

```
.parenthead, .testimonial_header {
background-color: #000000;
padding: 35px;
height: 550px;
}
.masthead .span6 {
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
text-align: justify;
left: 615px;
float: left;
}
.masthead {
color: #fff;
margin-bottom: 40px;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 30px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
height: 300px;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.masthead p {
color: white !important;
font-size: 15px;
width: 90%;
line-height: 30px;
}
.subscribe {
position: relative;
top: 140px;
width: 80%;
float: left;
left: -15px;
}
.masthead img {
width: 100%
}
#mobile
{
display:none; 
}
@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 200px)
{
#mobile
{
display:block; 
}
#web
{
display:none; 
}

}
```

Html:

```
<div class="parenthead">
<div class="masthead">
<img src="https://ifixandrepair.com/ifar/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/banner_web_1140x476.jpg" id="web">
<img id="mobile" src="https://ifixandrepair.com/ifar/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/banner_1_PNG.png"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="span6">
     <h1>Connect with us!</h1>
     <p>iFixandRepair helps get your mobile device back up and running again, servicing screen replacement, speaker repair, & more on phones, tablets, & computers.</p>
     <div class="social_button">
     <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/IFix-And-Repair/242100755854336" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" target="_blank" onclick="track_event('External Link', 'Facebook Home')">
     <i class="icon-facebook"></i> Facebook
     </a>
     <a href="http://www.twitter.com/iFixandRepairW" class="btn btn-info btn-large" target="_blank" onclick="track_event('External Link', 'Twitter Home')">
     <i class="icon-twitter"></i> Twitter
     </a>
    <a href="tel:+5619078349" class="btn btn-call btn-large">
    <i class="icon-phone"></i> Call Us</a>
    </a>
    </div>
   <div class="subscribe">
   <?php echo do_shortcode( ' [sies_subc_form]' ); ?>
   </div>
   </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the support for different screen resolutions with any one of below options:

1. Use Absolute positioning
2. Use of 
   `display: inline-block` also ensures the rows are not staggered.
3. Use of CSS3 media queries will also serve the purpose.

I would recommend to use media queries.

Comment: media queries for each and every screen? isn't it a bad practice?

Comment: No, I believe one media element serve for all screens sizes, if you maintain all dimensions in percentage of total screen size. CSS will handle it automatically. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: can u please give me one sample of media query and dimensions in percentage in my context?